# How many times to ensure the overlap is large

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Say we have $n$ balls, where $n$ is large. each time we draw $\log n$ balls with replacement, say the $i$th time you pick set $i$. For how large $k$ can we ensure that we can find $i,j<k$ such that the overlap of set $i$ and set $j$ is larger than $\epsilon\log n$ for some fixed $0<\epsilon<1$?

In other words, given a positive integer $n$, and $\epsilon\in \Bbb R^+,$ what is the smallest number $k$ such that for any $k$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, each with size $\log n$, there will exist two subsets whose intersection has size at least $\epsilon \log n$?

Lower bound for $k$ clearly $\frac{n}{\log n}$. But I don't know how find the upper bound.

Comment: How many sets are you creating? That has a significant impact on the size of the overlap.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yeah I'm asking for how many sets I can ensure the size of overlap to be large

Answer (score 1):

Here is a deterministic bound. But a probabilistic bound would be much more interesting. (I haven't worked it out yet)

Let $T\leq n$ denote the total number of balls included in the union of all $k$ sets. We have
$$n\geq T = \sum_i |A_i| - \sum_{\langle i, j\rangle}|\cap(A_i, A_j)| + \sum_{\langle i,j,k\rangle}|\cap(A_i,A_j, A_k)|-\cdots$$
$$\geq \sum_i |A_i| - \sum_{\langle i, j\rangle}|\cap(A_i, A_j)| = K\log n- \sum_{\langle i, j\rangle}|\cap(A_i, A_j)|$$
which may be re-written as
$$K\leq \frac{n}{\log n} + \frac{1}{\log n}\sum_{\langle i, j\rangle}|\cap(A_i, A_j)|\leq \frac{n}{\log n}+\varepsilon\frac{K(K-1)}{2}$$
Or
$$\boxed{K\Big[1-\varepsilon\frac{K-1}{2}\Big]\leq \frac{n}{\log n}}$$
which is non-trivial for
$$\varepsilon<\frac{2}{K-1}\leq\frac{2}{n/\log n-1}$$